# Im having problems to understand the removeFromCart implementation in Redux shopping Cart example

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im not sure where adn how implement the function removeProduct and how to define it..the basic idea is implement a removeProductFromCart functionality in the Redux shopping Cart example
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart

what I tried so far:

action.js

```
           const deleteFromCart = productId => ({
                 type: types.REMOVE_PRODUCT,
                 productId
            })

           export const removeProduct = productId => (dispatch)=> {
                  dispatch(deleteFromCart(productId))
            }
```

cartReducer.js

```
           const addedIds = (state = initState.addedIds, action) => {
                   switch (action.type) {
                       case ADD_PRODUCT:

                       if(state.indexOf(action.productId) !== - 1){
                             return state
                       }
                       return [ ...state, action.productId ]

                       case REMOVE_PRODUCT:

                           return state.filter(productId => action.productId !== productId)

                       default:
                           return state
                    }
              }

          const quantityById = (state = initState.quantityById, action ) => {
                  switch (action.type) {
                       case ADD_PRODUCT:
                  const { productId } = action
                  return {
                        ...state,
                        [productId]:(state[productId] || 0) + 1
                  }
                       case REMOVE_PRODUCT:
                  return { 
                        ...state,
                        [productId]: state[productId] - 1
                  } 
                     default:
                         return state
                  }
             }
```

Cart.js

```
     const Cart = ({products, total, onCheckoutClicked, 
     onDeleteFromCart }) => {

     const hasProducts = products.length > 0

     const nodes = hasProducts ? (

     products.map(product =>

         <div key={product.id}>

            <Product
             titulo={product.titulo}
             price={product.price}
             quantity={product.quantity}
             />
            <button
             onClick={onDeleteFromCart}
             disabled={product.inventory < 0 ? 'disabled' :'' }>
            {product.inventory < 0 ? 'Sin productos' : 'Sacar del carrito'}
             </button>

          </div>
         )
       ):(<p>Agregá productos al carrito</p>)

       return (
            <div>
                <h3>Tu Carrito</h3>
                <div>{nodes}</div>
                <p>Total: &#36;{total}</p>
                <button onClick={onCheckoutClicked} disabled={hasProducts ? '' : 'disabled'}>Checkout</button>
             </div>
                )      
               }

          Cart.propTypes = {
           products:PropTypes.array,
           total:PropTypes.string,
           onCheckoutClicked:PropTypes.func,
           onDeleteFromCart:PropTypes.func
      }

    export default  Cart
```

CartContainer.js

```
const CartContainer = ({products, total, checkout, removeProduct}) => (

  <Cart
     products={products}
     total={total}
     onCheckoutClicked={()=>checkout(products)}
     onDeleteFromCart={()=>removeProduct(products.map(product => product.id))}
  />
)

CartContainer.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    titulo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    quantity: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  })).isRequired,
  total:PropTypes.string,
  checkout:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeProduct:PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: getCartProducts(state),
  total: getTotal(state)
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { checkout, removeProduct }
)(CartContainer)
```

this code returns an array when I dispatch the action REMOVE_PRODUCT...
so I don't end to understand how I can make it works..the code don't trows error but how can I retrun just the id of the product? and not the array..its correct implement the functionality in CartContainer and cart? ...makes sense to my...but I seen some code where the implemntation is in productitems.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you'll likely want to fix.

First, your `action.js` is a little redundant. You should just be able to have:

```
export const removeProduct = productId => ({
             type: types.REMOVE_PRODUCT,
             productId
        })
```

Next, in your reducer, you'll want to make sure you spread your state and then filter through the specified array. I'm assuming your initial state for the reducer looks something like:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: [] <--- An array of products in the cart
}
```

If this is correct, then `case` in your reducer should look something like:

```
case REMOVE_FROM_OBJECT_ARRAY:
        return {
            ...state,
            products: state.products.filter(product => product.id !== action.productId),
        };
```

After that, when you need to pass your `removeProduct` action to your `<Cart/>` component, it should be:

```
onDeleteFromCart={this.props.removeProduct}
```

Since you are assigning that action to props.

Lastly, you'll need to pass the ID of the product into the `onClick` method of your button where you are triggering the action:

```
onClick={onDeleteFromCart(product.id)}
```

I hope this will get you headed in the right direction.

**Edit**

Try converting to class:

```
class CartContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
   // You may not need the constructor
}

handleRemoveProduct = (e, id) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.props.removeProduct(id)
}

render() {
  return(
    <Cart
      products={products}
      total={total}
      onCheckoutClicked={()=>checkout(products)}
      onDeleteFromCart={()=>removeProduct(products.map(product => 
      product.id))}
    />
  )
}

CartContainer.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    titulo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    quantity: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  })).isRequired,
  total:PropTypes.string,
  checkout:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeProduct:PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: getCartProducts(state),
  total: getTotal(state)
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { checkout, removeProduct }
  )(CartContainer)
```

Then pass this function into your `<Cart/>` component via:

```
onDeleteFromCart={this.handleRemoveProduct}
```

Then in your button:

```
onClick={(e) => onDeleteFromCart(e, id)}
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying to implement it, but so far this line of code "onClick={Delete From Cart(product.id)}" throws an error..just like an infinite loop..

Comment: You might try turning your `CartContainer` component into a class and writing a function to prevent the default behavior. I'll update in a moment.

Comment: great...the code has a new behavior..without change anything in the code that I post first...removes the product but removes all quantity of a same product, does not remove just one with one click...removes all products..with the same id with one click

Comment: sorry just change the reducer...insted:

case REMOVE_PRODUCT:

                           return state.filter(productId => action.productId !== productId)

I chaged for this

case REMOVE_PRODUCT:

      return [ ...state.slice(0,state.indexOf(action.productId),
        ...state.slice(state.indexOf(action.productId) + 1))
      ];

Comment: Can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477055/how-can-i-dispatch-function-in-redux

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet and sorry for that. I will delete this later. I don't understand what exactly you want to do. Do you want to remove Id from an array or return id?

Comment: the idea is add a removeProduct from the cart component functionality...(Im studing Redux and React..) so far the code that I tried logs in the console.."type: "REMOVE_PRODUCT", productId: Array(1)"...and nothing else happen..